# GCP cloud sql export is failing with an unknown error from console, gcloud sql export shows an error it is taking longer time than expected

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, export, gcloud, google-cloud-sql

I tried exporting from Console, also using offload export.
I tried using gcloud sql export command and I have also tried wait command.

gcloud sql export sql instance-name gs://bucket/filename.gz --database=db_name --project=project-id

Then I got the following error.
...is taking longer than expected. You can continue waiting for the operation by running `gcloud beta sql operations wait...
So I used the following command.

gcloud beta sql operations wait --project project-id operation-id --timeout=unlimited

Still it is failing. Could someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The message you mentioned does not mean the export failed, it just tells the user that gcloud is going to exit because the export may take a significant amount of time to complete. Have you checked your bucket if a file was created or not?

If it did fail, there are a few reasons you may check:

- Check for available disk space
- Another operation is already running. You may encounter this if you rerun your command and the previous one has not completed yet.
- There's an ongoing maintenance when you ran the export